# remove button padding on active in IE

Tags: css

In IE for button elements, when you click the button the text gets pushed down, it's like additional padding as been added to the button when active or click.

Any idea how to remove this? I've tried adding:

```
button:active, button:focus{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 outline: 0;
}
```

but this doesn't do anything.

Thank you!

Comment: Could we see an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE7? Put `overflow:hidden` to the button

Comment: Note this bug re-surfaced in the IE11 preview. Hopefully this is fixed before RTM.

Answer (score 0):

I believe putting it is putting a border so by adding border:none should get rid of it. In any case you should be using a reset like [Eric Meyers](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/) reset which puts all browsers at an even playing field